# SpaceVim: difficulty getting simple cpp and header file to compile and run

Tags: spacevim

I have a very simple structure:

```
myproject\
    src\
        main.cpp
    include\
        maininclude.h
    .clang
```

`main.cpp` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "maininclude.h"
int main(){
  foo_ f;
  f.seta(5);
  printf("value of f.a is %d\n", f.geta());
  getchar();
}
```

`maininclude.h` is

```
class foo_{
  private:
  int a;
  public:
  int geta() const {return a;}
  void seta(int val) {a = val;}
};
```

`.clang` is:

`-I./include`

When I then hit `<space> l r` after opening `vim` from `myproject\` folder, there the `Runner` window opens but nothing is displayed. Image displayed below.

[image]

Is there a separate window where the output is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `getchar();`, because this function is waiting for input. Or you can press `i` in runner buffer, and then insert any character.

[image]

Comment: Oh Hi. Thanks for coming in and answering. Since I posted that about a year ago, I have moved on. I tried very hard to have vim as my ide, tried other setups, etc, but my conclusion is that it is simply more productive *for me* to stick to stuff that works out of the box such as VSCode or Visual Studio.